# Passing a model instance, not __unicode__ method in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I've got a django form that contains a join via a foreign key.  This is a foreign key to a very large table.  On the form, to prevent loading up a massive select that tends to crash browsers, I've got a jQuery autocomplete, which on each keystroke sends off the entered text.  This text is then searched in the table and suitable results are returned to be displayed.  The id is then passed to a hidden CharField when one is selected.  This hidden CharField is the widget for the ForeignKey relation.  When I try to save the form, I get an error that I need to be passing a model instance for the related model, which is fair enough.  I can't work out how to do this however.  I can take that id and do a `model.objects.get(pk=id_from_form)`, but if I replace the POST data with the result of this, I still get an error as I'm just passing the `__unicode__` method of the model.  I'm sure there's something I'm missing, but I can't see what it is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `CharField` to store the id, try using a `ModelChoiceField` with the widget set as a `HiddenInput`.  The field definition in your form would look something like:

```
mymodel = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, queryset=MyModel.objects.all())
```

Comment: While I could do that, I don't really want to since I want to avoid loading every item from the related model into the form.  Initially, that table contains ~8000 rows, and that's only going to increase as time goes by.  From experience, loading that much data is slow and liable to drive the browser into the ground, especially on slow machines.

Comment: In the case of the default Select widget, the app and browser do need to load all 8000 rows.  If you use the HiddenInput widget, the validation is all performed server side using the provided QuerySet and never loaded by the browser.  Further, the QuerySet SHOULD be lazily evaluated such that all 8000 rows are never actually retrieved from the db.